# Guided tours of Japanese nuclear power plants

Tags: japan, tours, guides, geek-travel

Do any Japanese nuclear power plants offer guided tours of their facilities? I'm aware that most nuclear plants in Japan are currently not producing electricity, but that's not a big problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aｓ many companies have, there is rarely a possibility to see the inside of a plant, but only to see a [kind of exhibition](https://www.chuden.co.jp/kids/pr/pr_tokucho/index.html), but stocked only with marketing material made for school tours etc.

Currently, nuclear power is the most sensitive and emotional topic in Japan and there are many movements against it. You can actually find a lot of [organized tours against nuclear power](http://coalitionagainstnukes.jp/?page_id=1622). There is a very high security concern currently that someone might try to damage a plant and therefore there are currently no publicly open tours inside plants, except for people related to the industry, [like this tepco employee](http://www.asobi-map.com/genpatu.htm).

Comment: I know Dutch plants used to offer tours, but only to special groups like highschool classes and student societies for physics departments. And then only after submitting lists of attendants well in advance to perform security checks on everyone. No ad-hoc admittance indeed, certainly not past the visitor center and gift shop located outside the security fence.